# Compare user given string with answer in c#

Tags: c#, string

Consider a program that askes you questions, like "what is the last site you visited?" and the answer would be "stackoverflow". The user is asked this question and gives the answer "stakovervlow" or "overflowstack". I still need the program to count it as a correct answer.

To compare normal strings I would use StringCompare class, but this wouldn't work in this case. I've searched the internet and found some articles about SOUNDEX and some algorithms to compare every char in the string and calculate the similarity percentage (like the damerau levenshtein distance), but i don't really know what is best.

Anyone knows if there is a class in .net to accomplish this or what the best way is to compare the user answer with the correct answer?

Comment: Google for spell check algorithms.

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance and http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein for a basic idea. I don't think there is a predefined class to accomplish what you want.

Comment: If this is going to be a security feature this seems like a horrible idea.  You should be required to put in exactly what you originally typed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx) there is the SpellCheck class. You can add customized dictionaries as well for words like "StackOverflow", that are not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is quite difficult.  The easy but tedious way is to create a dictionary or a table in your database that lists common misspellings.

The difficult way is to try to write some code to do natural language processing.  The 2 most successful endeavors into this are the semantic search by Google and IBM's Watson supercomputer.  I gather you won't be duplicating their methodology anytime soon.